# Convertir linea de vb a C#

Tags: c#, vb.net

Tengo el siguiente codigo VB

```
Funtion Encripta(ByVal Pass As String) As String
Dim Clave As String, i As Integer, Pass2 As String
Dim Car As String, Codigo As String
Clave="%ü&/@#$A"
Pass2=""
For i=1 to Len(Pass)
      CAR=Mid(Pass, i, 1)
      Codigo=Mid(Clave, ((i-1) Mod Len(Clave)) +1,1)
      Pass2= Pass2 & Right("0" & Hex(Asc(Codigo) Xor Asc(CAR)), 2)
Next i
Encripta = Pass2
```

Quiero pasarlo a C#, la cual la llevo hasta el momento asi

```
public string Encripta(string Pass)
        {
            string Clave;
            int i;
            string Pass2;
            string CAR;
            string Codigo;
            Clave = "%ü&/@#$A";
            Pass2 = "";
            for (i = 1; (i <= Pass.Length); i++)
            {
                CAR = Pass.Substring((i - 1), 1);
                Codigo = Clave.Substring(((i - 1) % Clave.Length), 1);

            }

            return Pass2;
        }
```

pero hasta el momento no logro comprender la ultima linea, cual seria la la equivalecia de esta linea en C#

```
Pass2= Pass2 & Right("0" & Hex(Asc(Codigo) Xor Asc(CAR)), 2)
```

Comment: Agregar la libreria de visual basic no es una opcion?? Asc hace varias comprobaciones que no son asi de simples de resolver en C#...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que es asi:

```
var substr = "0" + ((int) Codigo ^ (int) CAR).ToString("X");
Pass2 += substr.Substring(substr.Length - 2);
```